# Laravel API Validation errors to be displayed

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, error-handling

I am valdating the fields sent through api and need to display the errors.
I tried using try and catch no errors thrown. I have already have a code validating the login

```
        try {
            $request->validate([
                'email' => 'required|string|email',
                'password' => 'required|string',
                'remember_me' => 'boolean',
            ]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }
```

I found no errors return  has json instead it is redirecting to the login page

How to handle rerros in API and sent the message as json?None of the example show the way to handle errors. I tried with everything

And also how to handle errors while creating the model

```
       try {
            $company = Company::create([
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'country_code' => $data['country_code']]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`$request->validate()` should automatically return a response to the browser with errors if it fails, it doesn't throw an exception.

If your request is json it should detect that and return the error in a json error response, you can catch this in your front-end javascript and interrogate the response to interpret the error message.
e.g. using axios:

```js
    this.$axios.post('your api url',{data})
            .then(response=>{
               // ALL Good
            })
            .error(error=>{
              // Catch returned error and process as required
            });
```

If as you say `I found no errors return has json instead it is redirecting to the login page` this probably means that Laravel thinks that the request is a standard request, in which case it will issue a `response()->back()->withErrors()` which is probably what's sending it back to your login.

Try checking the original request type and ensure it's `json`, it should have a header of `Accept: application/json`.

Alternatively you can define your own validator
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#manually-creating-validators, and process the validation on the server as you like.

Comment: I am using postman to send the data.It is sending it as post fields. Do I need accept json data in the API

Comment: I use Postman too and it works correctly for me.  Try logging out the `$request` variable before you call `validate` to see what it is set as?

Comment: content-type is multipart/form-data.How do use postman to send json data

Comment: @BLPraveen I've added to the answer, I think the request should have an `accept` header set to `application/json`

Comment: I  checked in the request it is having 'accept' has \*/\*. Where I need to change it. is it postman or in the controller

Comment: I change in postman the header accept to *application/json. it is showing the errors. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If there is error into validation then it will automatilly handle by laravel. You don't need to catch exception for that. It doesn't through exception.

Look it sample function which I have used for store Region

```
    public function createRegion(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        // Create a new validator instance.
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'details' => 'required'
        ]);
        try {
            $region = new Region();
            $region->name = $data['name'];
            $region->details = $data['details'];
            $region->save();

            $content = array(
                'success' => true,
                'data' => $region,
                'message' => trans('messages.region_added')
            );

            return response($content)->setStatusCode(200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $content = array(
                'success' => false,
                'data' => 'something went wrong.',
                'message' => 'There was an error while processing your request: ' .
                    $e->getMessage()
            );
            return response($content)->setStatusCode(500);
        }
    }
```